# Creating a Python 3/Pygame "Press Any Key to Continue" Start Page

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I know I'm probably making a very basic mistake here, I have been learning python for about a week and change, and I am trying to create a start screen for a text adventure game that allows the user to press any key to continue to the next screen which is expressed as a function, only it is not working despite attempting many permutations.

'''

```
import time
import pygame
import os
from pygame.locals import

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pygame.display.set_caption("GK-Sierra\'s Text Adventure - Comic by Tom Siddell")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1800, 1000))

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
FUCHSIA = (255, 0, 255)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)
LIME = (0, 128, 0)
MAROON = (128, 0, 0)
NAVYBLUE = (0, 0, 128)
OLIVE = (128, 128, 0)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
TEAL = (0, 128, 128)

def title_screen():
    title_screen_display = True
    while title_screen_display:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                title_screen_display = False
        font = pygame.font.Font('spiritmedium.ttf', 40)
        logo_image = pygame.image.load('logo.jpg')
        title_screen_image = pygame.image.load('tictoc.jpg')
        title_screen_image2 = pygame.image.load('firehand.jpg')
        title_screen_soundtrack = 'bythewall.mp3'
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        screen.blit(title_screen_image, (520, 100))
        screen.blit(title_screen_image2, (0, 600))
        screen.blit(logo_image, (600, 0))
        text = font.render('Press Any Key To Continue', True, PURPLE, BLACK)
        textrect = text.get_rect()
        textrect.center = (900, 950)
        screen.blit(text, textrect)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(title_screen_soundtrack)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)

def input_screen():
    input_screen_display = True
    input = ""
    font = pygame.font.Font('spiritmedium.ttf', 50)
    while input_screen_display:
        for evt in pygame.event.get():
            if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                if evt.unicode.isalpha():
                    input += evt.unicode
                elif evt.key == K_SPACE:
                    input = input + " "
                elif evt.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                    input = input[:-1]
                elif evt.key == K_RETURN:
                    input = ""
                elif evt.type == QUIT:
                    return
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        block = font.render(input, True, PURPLE)
        rect = block.get_rect()
        rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
        screen.blit(block, rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            name()
            pygame.quit()
        time.sleep(7)
        quit()

title_screen()
input_screen()
```

'''

Comment: `while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():` will continue looping while there is music playing, no? Meaning that you will be stuck in this loop until the music has finished

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and believe me when I say I couldn't hold a shout in... because I couldn't.

Establish a variable

```
window = 0
```

```
if window == 0:
(Title screen)

if window > 0:
(Rest of windows, to avoid each click setting the window value to 1)

elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    window == 1
```